# Independence number of $4$-uniform regular hypergraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph

Let $H$ be a $4$-uniform hypergraph on $[1..n]$, i.e. $H$ is a collection of $4$-element subsets of $[1..n]$. The elements of $H$ are called edges. A hypergraph is regular if every element of $[1..n]$ are in the same number of edges.

An **independent set** $I$ of $H$ is a subset of $[1..n]$ such that $I$ does not contain any edge. The **independence number** of $H$ is the maximal cardinality among independent sets of $H$.

**Question:**

Does there exist two positive numbers $c$, $d$ such that every regular 4-uniform hypergraph on $[1..n]$ with size $<cn^3$ has an independent set with size $d\sqrt{n}$?

**Motivation:**

Consider the problem of finding a Sidon set in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. If we relax the problem by allowing 3-term arithmetic progressions, the problem can be encoded into hypergraph independence: $H=\{\{a,b,c,d\}|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}_n,b-a=d-c ≠0,a≠c,a≠d\}$. Sidon sets are independent sets of  $H$, the largest with size $\sqrt{n}(1+o(1))$. I would like to find a purely combinatorial analog of Sidon sets, with similar size and constraints. Randomized methods give independent sets with size $c\sqrt[3]{n}$.

References about hypergraph independence featuring some group structure (hence not "purely combinatorial") are also welcome.

Comment: In the question, do you want a lower bound on the size of the independent set also? Otherwise any 3-element set is independent and size $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Why is a 3-element set of size $O(\sqrt{n})$ for large $n$?

Comment: Using what I understand to be the definition of "big-O" notation (e.g., here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), the constant function $3$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I have corrected the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general no. Partition the vertices onto $n/k$ subsets (I call them classes) of size $k$, where $k$ grows as $n^{2/3}$. Take into your hypergraph all 4-edges with the vertices in the same class. It has about $(n/k)k^4=nk^3\sim n^3$ edges, but each independent set contains at most $3$ vertices from each class, thus $O(n^{1/3})$ vertices.

Well, your graph is different and the things may go better.